how to separate the structure and style of a table in a .cls file, and pull the contents to populate the table from another file?
I have the file 'poscomp.cls', which contains the table:
 \begin{table}[hbt!]
  \ifthenelse
   {\equal{\@nivel}{mestrado}}
   {{\textbf{CRONOGRAMA DE ELABORAÇÃO DE DISSERTAÇÃO – ANO 1}}}
   {{\textbf{CRONOGRAMA DE ELABORAÇÃO DE TESE – ANO 1}}}
  \centering
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
  \begin{tabular}{llclllllllllll}
   
  \rowcolor[HTML]{A8D08D} 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9} & 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE} & 
  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{A8D08D}\textbf{ANO 1}} \\
   
  \rowcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9} &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE} &
  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C5E0B3}\textbf{MESES DO ANO (2021 - 2022)}} \\

  \multirow{-3}{*}{
  \cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}\textbf{ETAPAS}} & 
  \multirow{-3}{*}{
  \cellcolor[HTML]{BDD7EE}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DURAÇÃO\\(MESES)\end{tabular}}} &

  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{1}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{2}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{3}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{4}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{5}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{6}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{7}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{8}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{9}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{10}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{11}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E2EFD9}\textbf{12}} \\


  % INÍCIO DA LINHA %
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Etapa 2 – Estudo da linguagem de programação a ser\\ aplicada no desenvolvimento do sistema\end{tabular} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX} &
   
  \multicolumn{1}{l}
  \checkmark &
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark &
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark \\
  % FIM DA LINHA %

  % INÍCIO DA LINHA %
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Etapa 2 – Estudo da linguagem de programação a ser\\ aplicada no desenvolvimento do sistema\end{tabular} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX} &
   
  \multicolumn{1}{l}
  \checkmark &
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark &
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark \\
  % FIM DA LINHA %   

  \end{tabular}}
  \end{table}

The lines are defined by:
  % INÍCIO DA LINHA %
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Etapa 2 – Estudo da linguagem de programação a ser\\ aplicada no desenvolvimento do sistema\end{tabular} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX} &
   
  \multicolumn{1}{l}
  \checkmark &
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark &
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark & 
  \checkmark \\
  % FIM DA LINHA %

What I want is: to dynamically fill in the table's rows as the user adds or removes them, via another file. In other words, the idea is that the user doesn't touch the 'poscomp.cls' file, but just adds the data in a separate file. Is there any way of doing this?

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.
